# codeigniter: is this correct way to grab parameter?

Tags: codeigniter

if my page is Company/add/4 (company is controller, add is the function and 4 is the id of that company)

is this how I would echo the id to another page:

```
public function add($id) {

    $data['data'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('locations/add', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

then on the view:

```
echo $data['id'];
```

This is working correctly but i'm not sure its the best way to do it. because it seems like it would make more sense to have:

```
public function add($id) {

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('locations/add', $id);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: what exactly is the problem here? the first one you did was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the **controller**

```
public function add($id) {
$data['id'] = $id;
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('locations/add', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

**On VIew**

just do `echo $id`

codeigniter passes an array to the view so that you can pass not only 1 but group of data to you're views, use the key that you assigned on the controller as the variable's name on the view

whatever you place on the key that will be the name of you're variable in the view

```
//controller
$data['test'] = 'test';
//view
var_dump($test);//string "test"

//controller
$data['test'] = array('1','2');
//view
var_dump($test);//array()

//controller
$data['test'] = 1;
//view
var_dump($test);//int "1"
```

so on and so forth